# PINVOKE query (unsigned long*)

Tags: c, c#-4.0, pinvoke

I'm trying to call into a C function that takes the following struct as a parameter:

```
typedef struct CSTRUCT
{
    unsigned long* p1;
    unsigned long* p2;
    unsigned long* p3;
    unsigned long* p4;
} CSTRUCT;
```

I need to call the function from C# and need to know the pinvoke C# equivalent for this C struct.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tool I find useful is the P/Invoke signature generator, available as a free [download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/CLRInsideOut2008_01.exe) (via MSDN Magazine and [this blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/01/12/p-invoke-signature-generator.aspx))

The c# code it generates is:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CSTRUCT {

    /// unsigned int*
    public System.IntPtr p1;

    /// unsigned int*
    public System.IntPtr p2;

    /// unsigned int*
    public System.IntPtr p3;

    /// unsigned int*
    public System.IntPtr p4;
}
```

Comment: both links are dead. i need such tools all are absent

Answer (score 2):

`unsigned long* p1` in C is simply a pointer which you would typically declare as `IntPtr` in C#. That's the easy part of the process.  The hard part is how to assign to the pointer.  Is the pointer to memory owned by the C code?  Or is it memory owned by the C# code?  And who writes to that memory, the C code or the C# code?  You need to know the answers to those questions before you can make forward progress.